# Initializing array in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm working on a project for an assembly class, and I'm having trouble figuring out why my code is seg faulting. I'm trying to initialize an array with 10 strings and later call a function in C to display each string in the array. I know it runs through the loop, r8 goes from 0 to 10, but I don't know if works correctly. Also, when I comment out the line calling the C function, the code doesn't fault. I'm not sure if the problem is with initializing the array or with the C function, and any help would be appreciated.

Here's where I try to initialize the array with msg, which is a string that says "This is the original message."

```
init:
        mov     r9, msg
        mov     [arr+r8], r9
        add     r8, 1

        cmp     r8, 10
        jl      init
```

Calling the C function:

```
s:
        mov     rdi, arr
        call    display
```

The C function, which should print out each message in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display (char *arr[]) {

        printf ("help");
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
                printf (" Message [%d]: %s", i, *arr[i]);

}
```

Comment: Pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes) each. Use `mov [arr+r8*8], r9` and make sure you have enough space in your array and that it is in writable section. Also, I hope `r8` is initialized to zero.

Comment: use the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/8c8Y6Gc8f. See also the fast version. Good learning resoiurce

Comment: @Jester Thank you, I fixed that problem. I ended up doing add r8, 8 and cmp 80 instead of what I have here. However, I can't get my C function to output the actual string. It keeps outputting the pointer. If you get a change to look I'd appreciate the insight.

Comment: The C code should use `arr[i]` not `*arr[i]`.

Comment: @dragonfly3515 please update to be the current (post fix you mentioned to Jester) and anything else needed to test (like a `.S` file for the assembly).